# Stop voiceover reading a text

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, user-experience, voiceover

I have a long text on my view, when I tap on it VoiceOver reads the text. 
Is there a default behavior to stop VoiceOver reading? 
If not, is there a way to do it programmatically? for example when the view receive a tap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to stop it? If the user navigates away from that item then voice over will read the next item...

Comment: What if the user decides to ignore this element after knowing enough about it? Should he select another ui element like a button or so on, or a tap on the view where there is nothing will stop voiceover?

Comment: If it isn't default voice over functionality, how will the user know to do it? This is (partly) why accessibility has traits, hints and labels.

Comment: I'm asking the question to know what are the standards in the matter. I'm new with VoiceOver interactions and want to understand it before designing the app with my subjective point of view.

Comment: Label / text field / text view all read out the full text. Web views read out each paragraph separately so changing to a web view and formatted text could be a good option for you...

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the content or the interface it is difficult to give a solid answer to this question but one way to approach this problem it to try to not think of the experiences between a VoiceOver user and any other user as different experiences in the first place.

If you don't want VoiceOver users to repeatedly hear a long string of text you probably are also making the assumption that other users are going to be skipping over it after they have read it once as well.

Consider altering your interface so that the information is only presented once in a flow or is only presented when the user needs it and requests it, like contextual help.

Again, not knowing the interface or the purpose of the text makes it hard to answer this question directly but I generally find that building one interface to be inclusive of everyone often helps to point out that what might be perceived as just an Accessibility concern is actually a broader user experience concern and not just confined to the VoiceOver interface.

I hope that helps a little bit.